# Should I put any name in the DBNAME in PHP Script for connecting Oracle database?

Tags: php, oracle

I have here a php scipt for connecting mysql database. I know the localhost what it is all about, the dbuser of course and dbpass. I am confuse what to input in dbname? Should I made a random name, anything I want? Because below the example is `dbtest` I was looking for the whole PHP script if I can find something that is connected to the word `dbtest`, but I can't find one. So maybe this is a made up name?

```
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'root');
define('DBPASS', '');
define('DBNAME', 'dbtest');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129544/discussion-on-question-by-leol-paladin-should-i-put-any-name-in-the-dbname-in-ph).

Answer (score -1):

I guess I figure it out and it is funny. When I close my Oracle browser and open it again I came across this login interface then I suddenly realize that the username It needed here is perhaps the database name or dbname I was looking.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LSc5.jpg)